# Java Maven - How to resolve the version if two third parties depend on different versions of a library

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a scenario as follows:

I am using maven as a build process. I am creating a web project in which I want to use a specific version of spring. This project also depends on a third party library which internally depends on different version of spring. I have a doubt that this will result two different versions of spring n class-path and unexpected behavior will be observed. I have few information which I wanted to get more clarification on.

1. Can I use maven BOM concept for this?
2. Can somebody explain with example how to achieve this?
3. Can somebody explain how do we make sure that third party wont behave abnormally if overall project depicts using a specific version using BOM?

If somebody can throw light on it and give a detailing reference, that would help me  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maven should know how to evict one or more of conflicting versions of an artifact.
However, you can influence that by simply excluding one of the transitively included dependency. 
Example: the following code excludes the io.netty (transitive) dependency. In this way, you'd leave maven with the only other version as you decide/prefer.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <!-- The exclusion below makes sure that this specific version imported by hbase does not end up deployed -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Regarding runtime behavior, you have to test and decide for yourself (that is if you aren't lucky to have your direct artifact that documents versions of its own dependency)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of BOM but this won't avoid the conflicting issue of libraries by itself. It's very common that projects have one or more library which depends on the same other with different versions. In this case, when you want to force some specific library version for that third party library you must explicit it in your POM by using < exclusion > markups. This is not an easy task, once that projects usually have many libraries. So you need a tool to provide you an easy way to visualize a dependency hierarchy of your project libraries. There are some IDE plugins for this. Some versions of Eclipse, for example, have the maven plugin included in it, which provide a Dependency Hierarchy view ( a kind of dashborad of libraries and their dependencies ). Once you detected a library which should not using other library dependency ( wrong version for example ), you go at the this dependency in the pom and use the exclusion markup adjust the dependency version. Using the tool will make this task very simple.